# Sentence Correction

Tags: auxiliary-verbs, conjugations

Which one is correct?

1. > What I want and how I want is matter.
2. > What I want and how I want does matter.
3. > What I want and how I want matters.

Comment: None of the original poster's suggestions are grammatically correct.  Also, "How" should not be capitalized in the middle of a sentence.

Comment: The third one is sort of right, but "how I want" is logically weird because unlike say, running, there is only one manner in which people "want".

Comment: How do I correct the third sentence?

Comment: Can you rephrase "How I want"?

Comment: I want to mean "the way or method  of gaining the thing I want ".  For instance, I want money but I do not want money through an illegal way. (Is this sentence correct.)

Comment: what about (1) "What I want and how I want it matters." (2) What I want and how I want to obtain it matters." (3) "Both what I want and how I want to obtain it matter. "

Comment: Looking at your last comment, I think in speech, you can go for it. You are *quite close* to what you mean and convey. If someone is saying -it's easy to earn money if you smuggle illegal goods. You may reply - No. I want money but how I want **does** matter to me. You can emphasize on 'does' that way. The last sentence is also okay. However, it suits better in a different context where 'what' you want is also unknown. 'want' followed by 'it' is a good suggestion. But I guess, you weren't aware/concern about it.

Comment: @Ale: My choice of formatting quotes within lists is intentional, and reflects the fact that the list contains a set of standalone choices for what to say, rather than being a quote with a list in it.

Comment: @MaulikV,  IMO phrases (not sure if they have a specific name) like these should have a corresponding question form obtainable by inserting "do", and then the meaning of the phrase is just an implicit answer to the question. "how much do you lift?" is answered by "how much you lift". In this case "what I want" becomes "what do I want?" which makes sense. But "how do you want" seems verb abstract at best, bizarre at worst. The question that we need an implicit answer to is "how do I want to obtain it?" so the phrase should be "how I want to obtain it".

Comment: I think @MaxW alternatives work.

Answer (score -1):

What I want and the way to obtain it do matter. 
"it"should be mentioned to connect the phrases. "How I want" sounds weird. We can paraphrase this part.

Comment: Please [edit] to include an explanation of *why* this is correct; answers without explanation do not teach the patterns of the language well.

Comment: Shall I delete it?